# Time series cross-validation, calculate RMSE for different forecasting horizions

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cross-validation

Following Rob J. Hyndman suggestions on how to do cross validation for time series ( http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/ ), I modified his original code to  evaluate how RMSE (not MAE) varies through different forecasting horizons.

Here is my code

```
library(fpp) # To load the data set a10
plot(a10, ylab="$ million", xlab="Year", main="Antidiabetic drug sales")
plot(log(a10), ylab="", xlab="Year", main="Log Antidiabetic drug sales")

k <- 60 # minimum data length for fitting a model
n <- length(a10)
horizon<-8
mae1 <- mae2 <- mae3 <- matrix(NA,n-k,horizon)
st <- tsp(a10)[1]+(k-2)/12

for(i in 1:(n-k))
{
 xshort <- window(a10, end=st + i/12)
 xnext <- window(a10, start=st + (i+1)/12, end=st + (i+horizon)/12)
 fit1 <- tslm(xshort ~ trend + season, lambda=0)
 fcast1 <- forecast(fit1, h=horizon)
 fit2 <- Arima(xshort, order=c(3,0,1), 
         seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=12),                                            
         include.drift=TRUE, lambda=0, method="ML")
 fcast2 <- forecast(fit2, h=horizon)
 fit3 <- ets(xshort,model="MMM",damped=TRUE)
 fcast3 <- forecast(fit3, h=horizon)
 mae1[i,1:length(xnext)] <- abs(fcast1[['mean']]-xnext)
 mae2[i,1:length(xnext)] <- abs(fcast2[['mean']]-xnext)
 mae3[i,1:length(xnext)] <- abs(fcast3[['mean']]-xnext)
}


rmse1<- apply(mae1,2,function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2, na.rm = TRUE)/length(a10)))
rmse2<- apply(mae2,2,function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2, na.rm = TRUE)/length(a10)))
rmse3<- apply(mae3,2,function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2, na.rm = TRUE)/length(a10)))

plot(1:horizon, rmse1, type="l", col=2, xlab="horizon", ylab="RMSE",
 ylim=c(0.65,1.05))
lines(1:horizon, rmse2, type="l",col=3)
lines(1:horizon, rmse3, type="l",col=4)
legend("topleft",legend=c("LM","ARIMA","ETS"),col=2:4,lty=1)
```

But RMSE for LM (rmse1) is almost constat, it seems to me quite strange.

[image: RMSE for different time horizons]

What I'm doing wrong?
Is there a better approach?
Thanks.